# Why can't Kotlin variables assigned from fields change in function?

Tags: kotlin, class, reference, field, variable-assignment

I'm trying to understand why can't a variable that is assigned from a class field change in a function. Consider this example:

```kotlin
class A {
    private var a: String? = "a"

    fun hello() {
        val b = a

        if (b != null) {
            // The compiler assumes that 'b' is always not null inside this branch

            b.length
        } else {
            // is null
        }
    }
}
```

Variable `b` is going to always be the same throughout the function (later is implicit non null in the if branch). So even if through concurrency I change the field `a`, the variable `b` does not change?

How is this possible? does Kotlin make a copy of the variable and assigns it to `b`? I thought assignments worked with references and such.

This can happen, as far as I'm concerned, with any type (String, Int, custom class, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, there's no way you can change them after you instantiated them. Thus, if another thread modifies the value of `a` after `b != null` was evaluated, it will not affect `b`'s value.

Actually it's not even the real answer because here we're just talking about nullity. `b` will point to whatever object was pointed by `a` at the moment of the assignment, but then nothing can change what b is pointing to because `b` is a `val`.

I was just mentioning immutability because the content of `b` could still change through mutation if the type was mutable, but the reference itself will never change.

For more clarity, let's make a scenario:

```
[thread 1] a = "hello" <state: a => h: String("hello")>
[thread 1] b = a <state: a => h, b => h>
[thread 2] a = "world" <state: a => w: String("world"), b => h>
```

In short, `b` points to the same object as `a` at the time of assignment, but it doesn't point to `a` itself, so when `a` changes, `b` doesn't care.

Comment: Ok, so when we assign `a` to a different object, for example, the older object is still referenced by `b` and `a` points to the new one (in this case `null`)? That makes sense, and when the function ends then the garbage collector can release the memory, in case of JVM at least.

Comment: Yes that's it !

Comment: To put it succinctly: **`b = a` copies the _reference_**, so that `b` will then refer to the same object that `a` currently refers to. If that object were mutable, then changes to it would be visible via `b`. But it does _not_ identify `b` with `a`; if `a` is later assigned a different reference, that won't affect `b`.

Comment: This is also something you need to rely on with nullable top-level `var`s, because even if you null-check that variable with `if (a != null)`, there's no guarantee that it will still be non-null when you get inside the *if* block. It could have been modified concurrently, so the only safe thing to do is make a local *copy* of `a` that you know won't change. You can do that with `val b = a`, and scope functions like `a?.let { }` implicitly make a copy before null-checking it and deciding whether to run the function block (where that copy is passed in as a parameter or receiver)

Comment: Or you just don't use mutability and concurrency together :p